# How to find ANDROID_ID from device NOT programmatically

Tags: android

I am currently retrieving my device's `ANDROID_ID` programmatically with the following code:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(this._context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

How can I retrieve the same ID "visually" from the device (so not programmatically)?

I have looked everywhere but I have not been able to find it in settings, and neither using apps such as DeviceId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no global `ANDROID_ID` anymore. Since Android 8 each application sees a different value. More specifically the value depends on the signature used to sign the application, the user (on multi users devices) and the device.

See [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) for more details

Answer (score 1):

We can split the answer into two parts, depending on which Android API level device has.

**Device with API level < Android 8.0 (Oreo)**

The `ANDROID_ID` value can be retrieved using this `adb` command:

```
# this will retrieve current user's ANDROID_ID
$ adb shell settings get secure android_id  
ba003ff1b4125132
# you can also get the value of each other user's value by specifying --user <USER_ID>
$ adb shell settings get --user 10 secure android_id  
3e6a5f43bd80ea6
```

On an emulator (or on a rooted device), you'll be able to find the `ANDROID_ID` using the following commands:

```
# first, switch into a root mode and open a shell
$ adb root
$ adb shell
# find which users exist on a device (this example shows two users having ID 0 and 10)
$ ls -l /data/system/users
drwx------ 4 system system 4096 2019-10-09 18:05 0
-rw------- 1 system system  267 2019-10-09 18:05 0.xml
drwx------ 5 system system 4096 2019-10-09 18:05 10
-rw------- 1 system system  385 2019-10-09 18:05 10.xml
-rw------- 1 system system  367 2019-10-09 18:05 userlist.xml 
# the ANDROID_ID located in settings_secure.xml file
$ cat 0/settings_secure.xml | grep android_id
  <setting id="31" name="android_id" value="ba003ff1b4125132" package="android" />  
# similarly, we can find user 10's value:
$ cat 10/settings_secure.xml | grep android_id
  <setting id="31" name="android_id" value="3e6a5f43bd80ea6" package="android" />
```

**Device with API level >= Android 8.0 (Oreo)**

Same technique as above can be used on 8.0 and later devices, however the (global `ANDROID_ID`) value it returns can be seen [only by system processes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/SettingsProvider.java#1100).

`adb` doesn't support retrieving a particular application's `ANDROID_ID` at this time, because its value is being written into a separate file (`settings_ssaid.xml`, while `adb` allows to access only values from `system`, `secure` or `global`). However, on emulator or on a rooted device this can be easily achieved:

```
$ adb root
$ adb shell
# here I'm using user with ID 0
$ cd /data/system/users/0
$ cat settings_ssaid.xml  
<settings version="-1">
  <setting id="0" name="userkey" value="E4FC4CFF14039F5AD44AD63F70007F85FDBBE1FF9BCB9FF5331B3FD33E057461" package="android" defaultValue="E4FC4CFF14039F5AD44AD63F70007F85FDBBE1FF9BCB9FF5331B3FD33E057461" defaultSysSet="true" tag="null" />
  <setting id="4" name="10072" value="9d5f269e42d4ca76" package="info.osom.ssaid" defaultValue="9d5f269e42d4ca76" defaultSysSet="false" tag="null" />
</settings>
```

In this example, I have one application with package name `info.osom.ssaid`, whose `ANDROID_ID` value is `9d5f269e42d4ca76`.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need the `ANDROID_ID`? If you need it for auhentication reasons, ( to know which device is which) , be advised that this value is not constant but may change overtime. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID).

The only value that is unique and constant and can be used to identify your device is it's MacAddress but even that is discouraged.

If you need this value for some other reason, ignore this answer.

Comment: this likely should be a comment, not an answer